# django model form modelform multipart

Tags: django, forms, model, upload, multipart

I'm newbie to web development. started with Django since I already do Python for AI.

I'm trying to use multipart to model. but it appears doesn't support.

```
/models.py

from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class ImageData(models.Model):
    lot_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    images = models.FileField(widget=ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))

class ImageDataForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ImageData
        fields = ('lot_number', 'images')
```

It seems I need to use 'forms' https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/
than...

do I need to write same code for forms? like

```
/forms.py

from django import forms

class ImageData(forms.Form):
    lot_number = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    images = models.FileField(widget=ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
```

guess must be a way to handle model and form in one code but could find it.

Comment: Did you set `enctype='multipart/form-data'` into your html form? See more about  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp

Comment: I just put {{ form }}